# Blue reputation marker on profile sidebar doesn't go back to original reputation when suspension ends

Tags: bug, reputation, design, profile-page, account-suspension

My suspension on Stack Overflow recently ended, but the blue reputation marker on the sidebar of my profile settings is still negative as though my reputation were still 1:

[image]

This is clearly a bug, because before my suspension it was over 1k. Also, the green box under "Top tags", which is also visible in the screenshot, says "1.2k" again, **like it did before I was suspended.

Comment: @ricardec welcome back ! I think this is [tag:status-bydesign], once you click on the reputation tab and come back/refresh the page it would be gone (but I only double-checked it on positive reputation or responses)

Comment: @Vickel hi again! :) I'm having understanding how it should be status-bydesign, as the suspension message says (my own words) _"while you're suspending your reputation will show as 1, but **it will be restored after your suspension**"_ - but this contradicts that.

Comment: ^ that  refers to you reputation stats, the left bar you are showing refers to "last changes or recent responses, which wipes clean after click and revisit/reload", AFAIK

Comment: As a note: currently, the blue marker says "-2729".  [My quarterly rep score](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter) says "-2629" (because I bountied off my rep early this year), which is exactly 100 more than the blue marker. Possibly related?